# Reacht JS: CSS not applied correctly when rendering asynchronously created array

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, prismjs

I am trying to display code snippets on a React JS app. For this I have an array of snippets that are obtained using the `fetch` API.

To achieve this I store the necessary information in an array, and then create the `Snippet` objects using the `Array::map` method.

However, when I try to display these snippets, I see that the `Snippet`'s CSS is not applied correctly. The problem seems to be the delay in the `fetch` calls. If these calls are not executed, it all works fine.

Some notes:
- To find the culprit I hard-coded the snippet's parameters. 
- To get an MWE I replaced the calls to the `fetch` API with a call to `sleep`
- If I remove the call to `sleep`, the snippet is rendered correctly.

Here is my code of the responsible class:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Container } from 'react-bootstrap';
import Snippet from './Snippet';

export default class Examples extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { snippets: [] };
  }

  sleep(ms) {
    return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms));
  }

  createSnippets = async () => {
    const snippets = [{ code: "int main(void)\n{\n  bool testing = true;\n}" }];

    await this.sleep(2000);

    return snippets;
  };

  componentDidMount() {
    this.createSnippets()
      .then(snippets => { this.setState({ snippets: snippets }); });
  }

  render() {
    const snippets = this.state.snippets;

    return (
      snippets.map((snippet) => {
        return (
          <div>
            <Container>
              <Snippet key={ "test" }
                title={ "test" }
                code={ snippet.code }
                language={ "cpp" }
                plugins={ ["line-numbers"] } />
            </Container>
          </div>
        );
      }
      )
    );
  }
};
```

The incorrect result is shown below [image: not good].

Here is the expected result: [image: expected]

I am using [prismjs](https://prismjs.com/index.html) to highlight the snippets. Here is my implementation for this:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Container } from 'react-bootstrap';
import Prism from "prismjs";
import 'prismjs/components/prism-c';
import 'prismjs/components/prism-cpp';

import "prismjs/themes/prism-okaidia.css";


export default class Snippet extends Component {
  highlight = () => {
    if (this.ref && this.ref.current) {
      Prism.highlightElement(this.ref.current);
    }
  };

  render() {
    const title = this.props.title;
    const plugins = this.props.plugins;
    const code = this.props.code;
    const language = this.props.language;

    console.log("Snippet: title: %s, plugins: %s, code: %s, language: %s", title, plugins, code, language);

    return (
      <div key={ title }>
        <Container>
          <pre className={ !plugins ? "" : plugins.join(" ") }>
            <code title={ title } ref={ this.ref } className={ `language-${language}` }>
              { code }
            </code>
          </pre>
        </Container>
      </div>
    );
  };
}
```

I added the `console.log` statement to see if the properties are set correctly, which they seem to be in both cases.

Comment: I think you would have got more responses if you had posted a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of your attempt. Right now this is too much code to review and provide any help.

Comment: You are absolutely right, this is a rather large chunk of code, however, if I remove the methods used to obtain the code snippets, the code is displayed correctly. It seems that the asynchronous calls are a contributor to the problem.

Comment: @palaѕн I managed to reduce the amount of code significantly, by replacing the delay introduced by the `fetch` API with a simple `sleep`.